# Arduino Get request and host server?

Tags: php, post, arduino

I am trying to have my arduino run a web server but also post a variable from time to time. I have the following code:

```
client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
client.println("Host: joeybabcock.me");    //
client.print("GET /writetemplocalserv.php?t0=");     
client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
client.println(sensorValue);
client.println("Connnection: close");
```

and the whole code here(It's quite a bit so only look through if you have to.): http://pastebin.com/TXPccYs3
This does not post the variable. if visited in the web browser to the exact same url, it does, however, work.

Comment: Is this a request or a response??? This is not valid HTTP. Read [RFC2161](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) before throwing bytes to network.

Comment: i need to submit a get request at the brginning of the program, than a standard response when a client connects. i have the standard response, just not the get request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RFC 2161](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), defining [http](/questions/tagged/http)/1.1, MUST always be followed when writing Web (HTTP) servers and clients.

Your code is a big mess:

```
client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); //Response
client.println("Host: joeybabcock.me"); //Response/request
client.print("GET /writetemplocalserv.php?t0="); //Request
client.println("Content-Type: text/html"); //Response
client.println(sensorValue); //Probably invalid...
client.println("Connnection: close"); //Request/Response
```

In a very, VERY, VERY brief way, if you want to request you do:

```
client.print("GET /writetemplocalserv.php?t0=");
client.print(sensorValue);
client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
client.println("Host: joeybabcock.me");
client.println(""); //mandatory blank line
```

For responses:

```
client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
client.println("Host: joeybabcock.me");
client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
client.println("Connection: close");
client.println("");
client.println("body data");
...
```

**Again, any HTTP request/response must follow [RFC 2161](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)!**

Comment: Thanks, I was not able to find any documentation on this.